# Primefaces datatable : can I add an object to the table

Tags: primefaces, datatable, primefaces-datatable

I'd like to add one line to a datatable. This line would be exactly the same kind of lines that the ones already in the datatable.

In this example, my list of cars can't be changed. And I have an extra car to add at the first line.

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{myListOf.cars}">
<p:column headerText="Id">
    <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
</p:column>

<p:column headerText="Year">
    <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
</p:column>

<p:column headerText="Brand">
    <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
</p:column>

<p:column headerText="Color">
    <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
</p:column>
```

and my extra car:

```
Car extraCar = new car;
car.setId("345434354");
car.setYear("2016");
car.setBrand("dfdsf");
car.setColor("Blue");
```

Comment: You are not totally clear.. are you looking for https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/collector.xhtml ?

Comment: please paste the managed bean code. (myListOf)

Comment: .. or even better, provide a [mcve].